# How to 'select' correct Textbox out of List<Textbox> which are created dynamically?

Tags: c#, list, textbox, controls

In a school project I have to create 'dynamic' (if that's the correct term) textboxes in a MouseClick event.. By clicking the recently created textbox another Form will be opened (by another MouseClick event).

In that new Form I want to change the text from the recently created textbox to the text I insert in the new.

My problem is that the right textbox isn't being updated when I created multiple ones, it always edits the last one I created.

```
    private int tbcount = 1;
    //Dynamische textbox
    private TextBox tbNewUseCase;
    private List<TextBox> textboxlist = new List<TextBox>();

    public frm_use_case()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Textbox clicks
    private void tbNewUseCase_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ucform usecase = new ucform(this, tbNewUseCase);
        usecase.Show();
    }

    //Update textbox text
    public void UpdateTbTekst(TextBox tb, string tekst)
    {
        tb.Text = tekst;
    }

    //Mouseclick on the form
    private void frm_use_case_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbTekst.Checked)
        {
                //Only in a certain area I want a textbox to be created
                if (e.X > 288 && e.X < 451 - 100 && e.Y > 66 && e.Y < 421)
                {
                    tbNewUseCase = new TextBox();
                    tbNewUseCase.Name = "tbUseCase" + tbcount;
                    tbNewUseCase.Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                    tbNewUseCase.ReadOnly = true;
                    tbNewUseCase.MouseClick += tbNewUseCase_MouseClick;
                    this.Controls.Add(tbNewUseCase);

                    textboxlist.Add(tbNewUseCase);

                    tbcount++;
                }    
         }    
    }
```

And this is the code from the other form that is created when one of the textboxes is clicked.

```
    private frm_use_case mnform;
    private TextBox currentusecase;

    public TextBox Currentusecase
    {
        get
        {
            return currentusecase;
        }
        set
        {
            currentusecase = value;
        }
    }

    public ucform(frm_use_case mainform, TextBox usecase)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mnform = mainform;
        Currentusecase = usecase;
    }

    //Calls the method that changes the text in the main form
    //tbNaam is a textbox.
    private void tbNaam_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mnform.UpdateTbTekst(huidigeusecase, tbNaam.Text);
    }
```

EDIT: My question has been answered succesfully by Steve!

Comment: What do you expect to be the correct behavior of your code?

Comment: Could you boil your problem down to say two sentences of description and about 11 lines of code?

Comment: @DrKoch I got the solution allready but I'll boil down my problem and code anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a list of TextBoxes in the first form MouseClick event.
In that code you initialize repeatedly a TextBox reference named `tbNewUseCase` with a new instance of a TextBox. At the end of the loop, the reference variable `tbNewUseCase` is referencing the last textbox created.

Now when you pass this reference to the second form the update happens on this instance, the other instances created dynamically and added to the list are not affected at all. So you could change only one textbox.

Now, if you expect the change to happen on the clicked textbox then your should change the way in which you pass the textbox to be updated to the `ucform`

```
//Textbox clicks
private void tbNewUseCase_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Here sender is a reference to the currently clicked textbox
    // and you could pass that reference to the ucform constructor
    ucform usecase = new ucform(this, sender as TextBox);
    usecase.Show();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not explaining my problem that well but you got it right anyways! By changing 'tbNewUseCase' to 'sender as Textbox' the changes I make in the other form affect the textbox I want it to affect, thanks a lot!